# WhirlyGlobe for Android?

Tags: android, 3d, geometry, xamarin.android, textures

Is there anything like WhirlyGlobe for Android?

I just need to place a texture on a sphere that can be manipulated by the user. It must also be able to place overlays at various latitudes and longitudes.

I don't want to include whole 3D engines and I don't really want to code with bunches of arrays and GL specifics.

Are there any options or is OpenTK the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started working on my own implementation: https://github.com/mattleibow/OpenGlobe
It is a bit rough and old, but I am hoping to work on this again sometime. 
Just in case someone is interested...

Comment: How did you run this sample in Android? ... I need to make a globe in android the same way as it's done in WhirlyGlobe .. How should i run this https://github.com/mattleibow/OpenGlobe  ??